# Running time of for loops

Tags: algorithm, performance, analysis

I'm trying the measure the running time of this code. But i'm confused. it's running time is n^3 or 2^n ?

Here is the code:

```
for i ← 0 to n do
 for j ← 0 to 2 ∗ i − 1 do
  for k ← 1 to 2^j do
   Let A[i] ← A[i] + A[j] + A[k].
  end for
 end for
end for
```

Comment: Which language is this, in particular, what is the operator `^` doing?

Comment: Assuming `^` is exponentiation, that looks like `Θ( n²2^n )`, which is not the same as `2^n`.

Comment: ^ operation is the exponentiation of course.

Answer (score 1):

It is neither nor. The complexity is O(n^2 * 2^(2*n)) = O(n^2 * 4^n). There may be a better bound, I did not do the detailed math.

Comment: But, I'm looking for a Theta notation

Comment: It is definitely more than n^3 and more than 2^n so your options are both incorrect. To find the Theta you need to do the details of the summation.

Comment: @Henry Is it not O(n^2 * 2^(2*n)) rather than O(n^2 * 2^(n^2)) ?

Comment: i found only O(n^4) how did you find n^2 ? @llya